# Counting items in a string in Excel

Tags: vba, split, excel-2010

I have a string mentioned below and I need to return the results in 2 separate columns

Column 1: Count all the locations separating by Semicolon. for the below example, there are total of 15 names which are joined with semicolon

Column 2: After this I need to count how many names START with A, B & C and how many do not.

```
A1604A;A3703E;A3703H;C2203H;F1001B;F1001C;F1001D;F1001E;F1001F;F1001G;F1001H;F1001J;F1001K;F1001L;F1001M
```

Comment: May I know why there is a downvote to this post. Care to share the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate the split array incrementing a counter array for A,B,C,Other;

```
Dim str     As String: str = "A123;A456;B111;C222;C333;ZXX;Y66"
Dim items() As String
Dim i       As Long
Dim pfx(3)  As Long
Dim key     As Long

items = Split(str, ";")

For i = 0 To UBound(items)
    Select Case Left(items(i), 1)
        Case "A", "B", "C"
            key = Asc(Left(items(i), 1)) - 65 '//convert to 0,1,2 for counter index
        Case Else
            key = 3
    End Select
    pfx(key) = pfx(key) + 1
Next

Range("A1").Value = "total: " & UBound(items) + 1
Range("B1").Value = "A total: " & pfx(0)
Range("C1").Value = "B total: " & pfx(1)
Range("D1").Value = "C total: " & pfx(2)
Range("E1").Value = "Other total: " & pfx(3)
```